# How can I use $variable in go template call

Tags: templates, go

i use the go template

it work:

```
{{range $k, $name := .userList}}
    <tr>
        <a href="/?id={{$k}}">{{call .Tr "hey"}}</a>
    </tr>
{{end}}
```

it not work: 
get the err : at <.Tr>: can't evaluate field Tr in type string

```
{{range $k, $name := .userList}}
    <tr>
        <a href="/?id={{$k}}">{{call .Tr $name}}</a>
    </tr>
{{end}}
```

i want use $name for the Tr func , how can i do ?

Comment: The use of $name is correct.  The problem is that `.` is a string.  A string cannot be indexed  by `Tr`.

Comment: what is your userlist pipe? can you describe your userlist? is it []string only?

Comment: @CeriseLimón the op specified the `Tr` as a func. So he can do this, i suppose.

Comment: The dot value is an element of userlist.  Did you intend to refer the Tr field of the root value passed to the template?   If so, use $.Tr.   Show the Go code.

Comment: @CeriseLimón if that's the fact, then the 1st try of the question wouldn't a success.

Comment: thank @Cerise Limón Enthusiastic answer，like you say , it need $.Tr , now it work !!!

Comment: thank @Shudipta Sharma Enthusiastic answer too, it is my fault , Actually,1st it not work too...

Comment: then it's ok since it is working